# Variable from a controller to a view without a foreach loop in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-blade

I want to show the content of an article created, I have a show method in my controller

```
    public function show_capitulos($id)
{

    $data=Capitulo::select('capitulos.titulo as capitulo','capitulos.descripcion','capitulo_secciones.contenido','capitulo_videos.video')
    ->join('capitulo_secciones','capitulos.id','=','capitulo_secciones.capitulo_id')
    ->join('capitulo_videos','capitulos.id','=','capitulo_secciones.capitulo_id')
    ->where('capitulos.id',$id);

     return view('administrador.capitulos.show')->with(['data'=>$data]);
}
```

And I want to pass that data to my view in Laravel, without using a foreach loop, but it keeps showing the error of undefined variable

I've read that you use the get() function to retrieve a collection of data and that with first() you get only one.

**UPDATE:**After adding the get() in my code a new error is showing 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QqVM.png)

This is what I have in my view

```
<div class="row" id="contenido-cursos">
      <div class="justify-content-between flex-wrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 ">
      <h2 class="title">Capítulo 1</h2>
      <h1 class="nombre-capitulo"> {{ $data->capitulo }}</h1>
      <div class="linea-capitulo"></div>
      <p id="titulo-capitulo">{{$data->descripcion}}</p>

      <h2 class="title sub">Contenido</h2>
      <p class="contenidocap"><br>{{$data->contenido}}</p>

      <a class="btn btn-theme btn-block title extras" href="#"><img src="{{asset('assets/img/recursos.png')}}">  {{ __('Descargar Cap1.pdf') }}</a>

      <a class="btn btn-theme btn-block title extras" href="#"><img src="{{asset('assets/img/test.png')}}">  {{ __('Hacer Test 1') }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the name of the undefined variable?

Comment: You don't have any `$data->titulo` property you have `$data->capitulo` instead

Comment: Now it's not saying that, now the error is **Property [capitulo] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: You wrote this: `capitulos.titulo as capitulo` you're aliasing your field you have to call `$data->capitulo`

Comment: and I'm calling it, but it keeps showing the same error

Comment: In your view you are trying to call `$data->titulo` somewhere please change that to `$data->capitulo` and run `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I just did all of that, thank you so much for helping me but stills give me the same error, idk why, because I've read tons of blog and that's the right way

Answer (score 4):

You are defining the query but not executing it.
After concatenating `where()` and `join()` you have to call `get()` to retrieve the results for the query.

Comment: Thanks, after so many times of editing that method I forgot tu put it back again, but in my view it keeps showing me the error of undefined variable